# A function Excel which sends back the date of Monday of the next week

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

i'm looking for a function in  Excel which sends back  the date of Monday of the next week.
I tried this, but it does not work correctly :

```
=TODAY()+WEEKDAY(TODAY()-2)-1
```

because it changing every day ! 
thank's for you're helpe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=TODAY()+8-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)
```

Comment: yours is better! ;)

Comment: it's work, but I just want to know, tomorrow the date well doesn't change until the next week.

Comment: @ Robin @ Mrig please the date well change tomorrow , i want it to change automatecly next week

Comment: @H.hisoka - Not able to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @ Mrig : does the date well change tomorrow ?  because the function is dynamic.                                                                                                     I want that the date change, but next week.                                            as example next week the date will be 13/06/2016

Comment: @H.hisoka - My formula will give you `06/06/16`(Monday) till `05/06/16` and from `06/06/16` to `12/06/16` it will give `13/06/16`(Monday) and so on. I guess this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:

```
=A1-WEEKDAY(A1-2)+IF(WEEKDAY(A1)=2,14,7)
```

[image]

Which for TODAY() is:

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-2)+IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=2,14,7)
```